# How to render react component function into template literal onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component, with some functions to generate new HTML content dynamically, and I'm using below code to get html text within the component:

```
let h_txt = `<li>
                <button onclick='{${this._makeAlert}}'>
                     ${o.text}
                </button>
             </li>`;
return(h_txt);
```

The problem is when I click on this new button, I got error:

Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.

How I can render a function inside temp literal?

Comment: Why not make this a React component instead of messing around with template literals? `const HTxt = ({ makeAlert, text }) => <li><button onClick={makeAlert}>{text}</button></li>;`

Comment: You are correct, this is the alternate way im using. Yet it is just a tiny component, im wondering if a more simple way might apply

Comment: You can define a React stateless component with a single line of code, as I've shown above. It's not going to get any simpler than that. Have you attempted it?